# What instance of `Num` is used with literals e.g. in `print 1`?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've just used haskell as calculator expecting to get some cryptic error message about ambiguity of the type instance of the numeric literal. But got none.

For example in ghci

```
> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
> print 1
1
```

It seems crazy that I expect code like `print 1` to break xD. But here ghci needs to use some implementation of `Show` class. Also the `1` is represented in some way in runtime. What representation is used and why doesn't it ask me to specify the type?

Simmilar example:

```
> 7*15+2
107
```

The expression has general `Num a => a` type but is calculated and for that some type needs to be chosen. Is it *Integer*? This behaviour of course makes sense but how does it work?

Typing e.g. `print $ 5 ^ 5 ^ 5` (outside of Int range) prints the correct number so I guess that it is *Integer* rather than *Int*.

I haven't found any general `Num a => Show a` instance, rather the implementations for types like Int are specific to them.

I've tested with ghc in versions *8.8.4*, *7.10.3* and *9.0.2*. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will perform type efaulting with `Integer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell has a type defaulting mechanism to avoid having to specify the type of every numeric literal you type. The default type for `Num` is `Integer`, while for `Fractional` (literals with a decimal point) it is `Double`. You can change these defaults using a top level default declaration. [This](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) article explains the defaulting rules

Answer (score 2):

> The expression has general `Num a => a` type but is calculated and for that some type needs to be chosen. Is it `Integer`? This behaviour of course makes sense but how does it work?

Haskell works with [type defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) and the default for a `Num a => a` type is indeed `Integer`. Since `Integer` is also a member of the `Show` typeclass, it will thus still use `Integer` and `print $ 5 ^ 5 ^ 5` will thus indeed use the `Integer` instance of `Show` to print the value.

Answer (score 2):

The default default is `(Integer, Double)`. More info [in the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4). You may also want to read about [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--XExtendedDefaultRules); notably this is on by default in ghci.